# Using Python to get Windows system internals info

Tags: python, windows-xp

I'd like to write some quick Python code to assess the CPU, memory, disk, and networking usage of my Windows XP system.

Are there existing Python libraries that would allow me to access that information?  Or, are there DLL's that I can call from Python? (If so, a code sample would be appreciated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think WMI is the resource to use. Especially, look at the [`Win32_PerfFormattedData*` classes in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(VS.85).aspx).

A quick search turned this up (among others):

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi.html

Answer (score 0):

The MS [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178) tool can generate WMI scripts in Python as well as VBScript, JScript and Perl.